# web.config vs. text file for storing a comma-separated value

Tags: web-services, iis, configuration-files

We have a collection of VB.NET / IIS web services on some of our servers, and they have web.config files in the websites' root directories that they're already reading configurations from.  There is a new configuration that needed to be added that will immediately be quite a bit longer than the others, and it'll only stand to grow.  It's essentially a comma-separated value, and I'm wanting to keep it specifically in a configuration file of some sort.

At first I started doing this with a text file, but there was a problem with that.  The text file's contents could change while web service threads and processes are running, so they would need to essentially re-read the file every time they needed to access its values.  I thought about using some sort of caching, but unless the web services are completely restarted each time the file is updated, caching would block updates to the file from being used immediately.  But reading from a text file each time is slow...

Then came the idea of putting that value in web.config, along with the other configurations the services are already using.  When web.config is altered, the changes are able to be cached in the code, on top of coming into play immediately.  However web.config is, well, web.config, and it's not a totally trivialized text file that is simply read out of in the code.  IIS treats web.config in a special manner.

I'm tempted to think any negative consequences of putting a comma-separated value in web.config would be outweighed, in comparison to storing them in a text file (or a database, which probably can't be used for this anyway), but I guess I better ask.

What are the implications of storing a possibly lengthy, comma-separated value in web.config, instead of in its own little text file?  Is either file a particularly good or bad idea?  To me, it seems like web.config would be easy to get along with without having to re-read the file over and over, but there's certainly more to it than the common user is aware.  Thanks!

Comment: Does this data change frequently? If so, web.config will be a bad idea.  Every time web.config is changed the app pool is recycled.

Comment: @Namrehs It'll probably have little spikes in how often it's changed, but most of the time, it should be fairly stable.

Comment: @Namrehs That's enlightening.  Do you want to use that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the Application Cache for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: A little bit of info for other folks: Key-value pairs in the Cache object can be set to become invalidated as soon as a given file is changed.  Combine this with putting the comma-separated list in a text or csv file, and you get pretty close to the best of all worlds.  The values are cached right up until the file is changed again, then they can be re-applied immediately, you don't have constant reading of the file, the app pool is not recycled, etc.  The only caveat is that you may have to fully qualify the name of the reference to the Cache object...

Comment: ...Instead of just saying `Cache("myKey")`, like their documentation suggests, you may have to say `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache("myKey")`.  Another work-around is to store a reference to `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache`, so that you don't have to type so much each time - optionally calling your reference itself `Cache`.